# Statement Terminated Because Data Will Be Trunucated

Tags: mysql, sql, vb.net

i'm facing an error anytime when i try to update my records in a database 
it indicates that statement is terminated because data will be trunucated 
please help

```
            Dim command As SqlClient.SqlCommand = con.CreateCommand()
            command.CommandText = "UPDATE staff SET  staff_pic=@staff_pic,fullname=@fullname,dob=@dob,gender=@gender,nationality=@nationality,hometown=@hometown,religion=@religion,tel=@tel,address=@address,position=@position,qualification=@qual WHERE Staff_ID=@ID"
            Dim mem As New MemoryStream
            staff_pic.Image.Save(mem, staff_pic.Image.RawFormat)
            command.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = staff_id.Text
            command.Parameters.Add("@staff_pic", SqlDbType.Image).Value = mem.ToArray()
            command.Parameters.Add("@dob", SqlDbType.Date).Value = staff_dob.Text
            command.Parameters.Add("@fullname", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = staff_lname.Text
            command.Parameters.Add("@gender", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = staff_gender.SelectedItem
            command.Parameters.Add("@nationality", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = staff_nationality.Text
            command.Parameters.Add("@hometown", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = staff_hometown.Text
            command.Parameters.Add("@religion", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = staff_religion.Text
            command.Parameters.Add("@tel", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = staff_phone.Text
            command.Parameters.Add("@address", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = staff_address.Text
            command.Parameters.Add("@position", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = staff_position.SelectedItem
            command.Parameters.Add("@qual", SqlDbType.VarChar).Value = qual.SelectedItem


            If command.ExecuteNonQuery() > 0 Then
                MsgBox("info inserted")
            Else
                MsgBox("info hasnt been inserted")
            End If
            con.Close()
```

Comment: Kudos for using parameters!  Check the lengths of the strings in the columns and how they compare to the data you want to insert.

Comment: Please explain. In code you use libraries for Sql Server, but in tags you have MySql. What is the right one?

Comment: @BlackDante101 For the `SqlDbType.VarChar` parameters, you can give it the size of the column in the database. For the `SqlDbType.Image` parameter, give it the size of the array.

Comment: @BlackDante101 Oh, and for the `SqlDbType.Date` parameter, you should parse the text to a date for the value - or if it came from a DateTimePicker then you can use the .Value of that instead of the .Text parameter.

Comment: how do i get the size of the array

Comment: @BlackDante101 You could `Dim img = mem.ToArray()` and then `command.Parameters.Add("@staff_pic", SqlDbType.Image, img.Length).Value = img`.

Answer (score 1):

it happens when you insert data larger than data type  length limit .
you either can alter your table and add larger number to column that reached its max or limit your inputs to fit your columns size.
cheers